# How to disable Next.js 13 React Server Components From Running at Buid

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, next.js13, react-server-components

My React Server Components access mysql with Prisma from inside a local network.  That is, I am running docker with mysql running in one container and my Next.js 13 RSC app running in another container.  The connection string I use to mysql from the RSC app just has the container name in it.  That is, something like this:

```
mysql://username:password@db:3306/mydb
```

> Server Components consumed inside the app directory will run during
> the build

How can I suppress this behavior so that my next.js docker image can build without a connection error in the github action build step.